# Why is careers so absent from some (reasonably big) cities?

Tags: discussion, jobs

There seems to be quite a disparity in [Careers.Stackoverflow](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) job listings between cities here in CO.  Boulder and Denver both list over 10 jobs each, but Colorado Springs has zero.  I know Denver is quite a bit bigger than C-Springs, but zero?

Are there reasons why this might be the case, other than simple expected randomness in rate of usage between cities?  Has the SE team marketed the careers site more aggressively in some cities than others?

Comment: Speaking as a (non-Native and therefore suspect) Coloradoan, COSprings is a bit of a wasteland unless you're into DoD-related work.

Comment: @Shog - *sigh*, I'm a non-native Coloradoan too, and I think there's a lot of truth in your statement.  I'm no pacifist, but *wasteland* and *DoD contract work* seem to go well together.

Comment: The job-listing already ignored some reasonable big countries having lot's of developers like India (just one job) and you are worrying about cities ;)

Comment: @Shog9 - well c-springs is [on Careers now](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/18072/mid-level-web-developer-current-usa?a=llOB4Wc) -- I convinced my boss to post our opening there.  Spend that $350 wisely :)

Comment: Woohoo! Best of luck, @Adam!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Adam the Careers team does not target specific cities. If you take a look at how Colorado Springs stacks up against Denver and Boulder on other sites, you will see the same trend :( Thus, this is more a reflection of the market than a specific marketing activity...BTW WE
LOVE COLORADO!

Comment: Fair enough - I never knew there was such a market in Boulder.  I always thought it was just a sleepy college town.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Never underestimate the draw of <strike>cheap labor</strike> college towns to employers...